# Running Multiple Excels having separate Macros without opening File

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 10 different excel files. For each file, I have a process saved in notepad
Every day i need to open each file, copy - paste the code from notepad to VB-excel & run the code

Is there any way I can kind of do this in batch file

Something like 
Open File1
Run code of File1.
Save File 1

Repeat the same for File 2

Pls help

Comment: Why don't you save the code within the excel files? Then through another app (e.g. Excel), open each file and call `Application.Run "Method".

Comment: @KostasK. Codes are kept in notepad 'coz i get new data everyday. I mean everyday the source send me these files. Hence codes are not saved in excel

Comment: You can use COM connected languages like open-source Python, PHP, R, even PowerShell to run Excel processes. Please show notepad code.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your macro in a "Personal Workbook" [described here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566).

The macros you store there load together with the Excel application and will be available to all workbooks you open.

Comment: tested this. seems to be working fine. the only issue is how do I convert my existing macros which i have store in notepad to personal.xlsm ? Pls suggest

Comment: You can directly paste your TXT files into code modules in your Personal Workbook or you can use the import function in the VB Editor to import TXT files directly. There is no issue because VBA copy is normally handled as TXT files by VBA. Whatever ran before will also run now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "Personal Workbook", I may even suggest automating that personal sub to open the workbooks automatically?

This could also potentially just point to a folder and For Each Workbook in definedSelectedWindowsPath

call subToAutomate()

similar to [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder)

BIG thanks to Mr. Newman, he has certainly saved my back from a few sleepless coding problems.